# java persistance query language limit resultset

Tags: java, mysql, jpql

Suppose I have following rows in a table "mytable"
id

1

2

3

...
...

500

and my query is like `select m from mytable m where m.id < 300`
how can I get following output in the same order?

201

202

...
...
...

299

I am using setMaxResult(100) but it returns me output like this

1

2

...
...

100

any advice?

Comment: please see your query, you want id less that 300 or greater than 200

Comment: If he wants to have datasets within a specific id range and it doesn't matter if all the ids are used within that range, then yes, this should be the easiest way (`... where m.id between 201 and 299`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setFirstResult` to define the start index. Together with `setMaxResult` you can get a specific range.

Comment: Yes but value in where clause is dynamic. So I don't know from where to start. There is a way to count rows first then issue a new query but I am trying to find a better way if exists

Comment: I don't think there is a good dynamic way to define the range in one query. If you want to have the first 100 just use `setMaxResults(100)`, if you want to have the last 100 use the reverse order and take the first 100. If you want to get another range in between you'd somehow have to know the number of results. You might be able to somehow get the number of results and calculate the range in one SQL query but I'm quite sure that isn't possible in JPQL. Could you provide more information on the context you need that for?

Comment: I have 10K rows in a table and I am binding this table with jtable where I am showing first 100 rows. I have also included 2 buttons in gui to navigate resultset i.e. Next, Previous, when user clicks on next button then I get last row of table where ID is also written. Then I make a next query to get results from > than id from last row which works fine. Now I am trying to go back for which I need the above query. Have u any idea how can I achieve this pagination functionality

Comment: In the general case you'd just select the number of results first (without any max) and then use `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResult` to do the pagination (you'd have to assign each page a range). If your data might change in between you could either check the number of datasets again (this should be quite fast) or use `where m.id > x` in conjunction with `setMaxResult`. Then the buttons should be assigned the value of `x` (you should load 100 + 1 entries in order to the the `x` for the next page, the `x` for the pev button should be known already, since I assume you loaded that page once).

Answer (score 2):

```
String ql = "select m from mytable m where m.id < 300 order by m.id";
Query query = em.createQuery(ql);
query.setFirstResult(200);
query.setMaxResults(100);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are taking about JPA, you can use [`order by`](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/order).

Either directly in your JPA query:

```
select m from mytable m where m.id < 300 order by m.id
```

Or using [`criteria`](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria):

```
CriteriaQuery<MyTable> q = cb.createQuery(MyTable.class);
Root<MyTable> c = q.from(MyTable.class);
q.select(c);
q.orderBy(cb.asc(c.get("id")));
```