# Sql query for pagination using hibernate and extjs paging toolbar

Tags: java, sql, oracle, extjs

Here is my query:

```
String queryString = "SELECT A,B,C,D from Table1 T1,TABLE2 T2"
              +" WHERE T1.A=T2.D"
              +" AND T1.B=T2.C";

int start=0,limit=15;
```

Here I am executing queryString by setting start and limit

```
List queryList = executeReadAllSQLQuery(queryString);


int totalcount = queryList.size();
System.out.println("before => " +totalcount);
String PaginationQuery = queryString+" LIMIT "+ start +","+ limit;
List queryList2 = executeReadAllSQLQuery(PaginationQuery); // **ERROR/EXCEPTION**
```

> Exception : Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to do pagination for that i have set start and limit.I want to fetch records based on the start and limit from database.

Comment: (BTW, a limit clause without an order by clause is almost always a bug)

Comment: if you are using oracle then it does not support limit clause..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634841/java-persistance-query-language-limit-resultset

Comment: If you're using Hibernate, he will do this for you, why are you still executing native sql queries and using hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

In Hibernate use this one please to limit your selection:

```
List result = session.createQuery("from TableName").setFirstResult(0).setFetchSize(200).list();
```

This will Select like this one limit 0,200

you can write the values you want in `setFirstResult` and `setFetchSize`

This one will be general with any DATABASE ENGINE

Regards,